# HttpRequestMessage POST request become GET - Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I am pretty new to Asp.Net Core and I managed to create a mvc project. In This project I have created an API and it is secured with token based authorization. I am trying to consume this api and make a post request to save data to database. To achieve this I have created one  API controller and one MVC controller. These two controllers are used with different purposes. In order to consume the api I have to generate a JWT token and attach token to request header. I use MVC controller for that purpose and after attach authorization header, I consume API post endpoint by sending request from MVC controller to API controller. Here is the process.

I have a form to collect product data in view. Data is send to the MVC controller through ajax. Ajax coding part is successfully working and I can see all the data have passed to controller.

**MVC Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> stockIn([FromBody] Products products)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var token = getToken(user);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
                                         "https://localhost:7015/api/stocks/stockIn/");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    request.Content = content;
        
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var apiData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return Ok(apiData);
    }

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
}
```

This code(MVC controller) also works fine, when I debug this just before the request is sent, I can see token and content also have generated and request is attached with them. Request method is also set to POST.[image]

Then I put a breakpoint on API controller and once the request is sent, the **Request Uri - Api endpoint** is hiiting and I can see that **request method has become GET and the content become Null**

**API Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("StockIn")]
public async Task<IActionResult> StockAdd(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
{
    var content = httpRequestMessage.Content;
    string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    Products products = new Products();
    products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Products>(jsonContent);
    
    await _context.StoresProducts.AddAsync(products);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(new { success = "Stock updated successfully" });
}
```

When I am hovering over the received httpRequestMessage on API controller :[image: received httpRequestMessage]

When I am debuging line by line API controller, A null exception is thrown When request message content access.

[image: Null Exception]

I found that there are many posts regarding this issue. I have tried almost every solution mentioned on them.

**Tried fixes: None of them work**

```
var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
     new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

I also tried changing request Url by adding '/' to end of it, does not work either. Some of the posts has guessed that there must be a redirection but I can not find a redirection also. I think sometime this caused because I am calling the api endpoint via MVC controller action. Since I want to attach token to request header before api calling, I can not find a way to call api endpoint directly without MVC controller action. Please help me to find the issue here or show me how to achieve this task correctly. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, don't use `.Result`, just `await` the call. Second, the error you show isn't the same as the code you show here so we cannot help.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by ' error you show isn't the same as the code you show here' ???

Comment: The image you show here with the error shows different code in the background to what you have posted here, they are not the same blocks of code.

Comment: there are two controllers. I am calling to second controller(API) through first controller(MVC). The errors are happening in second controller. Just same as I showed you. My point is actually not the null exception. I found that the null exception occur because the httpRequestMessage content become null and I realized that happens because POST became GET when calling api controller. I have showed you the same code.

Comment: Yes, I see 2 controllers, but you cannot expect us to help when the exception message you post is from code that you have not shown here.

Comment: I have posted API controller. That controller expects httpRequestMessage, as you can see in the line **public async Task<IActionResult> StockAdd(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)**.  Putting breakpoint on that controller and hovering over httpRequestMessage, I can see the content is null and Method has become GET as I showed you. And in the same controller when reaching the line **string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;**, the null exception is thrown.

Comment: When a client send a POST (a request with a body) the server will receive with a GET.  When a server sends a response with a POST the client will receive with a GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particula reason you're expecting the body to bind to the HttpRequestMessage?
Have you tried changing the post action to bind to the correct object?

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("StockIn")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> StockAdd(IEnumerable<Products> products)
        {
            await _context.StoresProducts.AddAsync(products);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok(new { success = "Stock updated successfully" });

        }
```

Comment: Since API controller is secured with token authorization scheme, I have to send a request object with authorization header and the content. Calling API without request object does not even reach the action method.

Comment: That does not sound right. The token would be validated by the middleware. Shouldn't really come down to the actual action. i tried your sample code on dotnet 6 and everything works as expcted

Comment: Then I might be missing some configurations. Can you show me how you achieved this??

Comment: Are both the controllers in the same project and hosted on the same server/port? If yes, then there is no need to call the API controller using HTTP client. It's another method in your project.

Comment: Yes, both controllers are in the same project. But Only API controller is secured with token auth scheme. Since it is secured, I can not directly call it without httpClient and authorization requset header. I create client and request object using MVC controller and then call API. It sounds like my flow is incorrect. Please, show me how to achieve this case correctly.

Comment: to send the content we create HttpRequestMessage and I thought that I must bind receiving content to HttpRequestMessage. I did same when you first suggest this solution but it didn't work. Now I realize It didn't work because I used **IEnumerable<Products>**, since I send details of one product I should use **Products product**. Thank you very much. It is perfectly working now. However I've seen in many posts objects are passed and received using HttpequestMessage. It did not work for me. Could you explain it why??

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this problem is related to redirect.
When you send request with some method and method changes after sending request, it will be about redirect.

Redirect occures in diffrent scenario:

- Wrong api address
- Authentication needed

As you said, sometimes url's that does not end with '/' cause to redirect

So send request with postman and check postman log (bottom-left) for better detail.

check if Redirect occoured or not,
if redirect occured, so check for reason. also check if WWW_Authenticate exist in headers.

Comment: I sent the request using postman. When it call **var token = getToken(user);** in MVC controller, it fails the authentication and throw **Unauthorized** exception. It didn't even reach the API. I think it's because the postman, this doesn't happen in App. If user logged in, token is generated successfully. Then I commented the first two lines of MVC controller and manually added a token. And I attached a authorization header to postman rand sent request. It is reached the API and breaks when the null exception occur. In console I didn't find a redirection and WWW_Authenticate header either.

Comment: when getToken(user);  called, this means your request reached to your api action. so you got exception inside getToken and authentication process could not be completed
trace getToken method for exception.

Comment: I'm sorry I have not showed getToken function here because that code work as expected. However, getToken function is included in MVC controler. I use Mvc controller to get the token and create request header before calling token secured Api controller. That is why I use two controllers here.

Comment: Really grateful for trying to find me a solution and as @Ceemah showed, changing HttpRequestMessage to relevant Model type solved the issue. Could you please explain me why HttpRequestMessage does not working?? I have seen objects are passed that way in many stackoverflow posts.